# How to catch error/validation error on onchange for Primefaces fileupload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using `passthrough` to pass the `onchange` to the PF fileupload component. I want to collapse a panel and expand another when the user selects a file.

The problem I have is that I am always collapsing and expanding the panels. I don't want tot do this in case an error occures. And by error, I mean if I add an unsupported file type. If I do this, the PF error message will be displayed, but the what is inside the `onchange` will also get called.

I tried using the `args` but this is not working for `passthrough`...

How can I check for those specific errors and only execute what's inside the `onchange` if there aren't any? Or can I catch them somehow?

```
<p:fileUpload disabled="#{userAccess.isDisabled()}"
    id="documentUpload"
    label="#{msg['components.fileUpload.chooseDocument']}"
    uploadLabel="#{msg['components.fileUpload.uploadLabel']}"
    cancelLabel="#{msg['components.fileUpload.cancelLabel']}"
    invalidSizeMessage="#{nts['error.documentType.invalidFileSize']}"
    invalidFileMessage="#{cc.attrs.invalidFileTypeMessage}"
    fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.documentsHandler.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced"
    dragDropSupport="true"
    oncomplete="PF('#{clientId}_addPanel').collapse();"
    update="#{cc.clientId}:displayPanel"
    process="@this"
    allowTypes="#{cc.attrs.allowedTypes}"
    styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}"
    sizeLimit="1000000"
    pt:onchange="if (tagName == 'INPUT' &amp;&amp; #{!cc.attrs.isLogo}) { if (!!value) {PF('#{clientId}_addPanel').collapse(); PF('#{clientId}_editPanel').expand();} }">
    <f:attribute name="document" value="#{cc.attrs.documentsHandler.document}" />
</p:fileUpload>
```

Update:

I even tried to get the DOM element where the messages are stored by class name like `console.log($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{cc.clientId}:addPanel')).find('.ui-messages-error-summary'));`

No success with this also, it doesn't find anything when using the `onchange` method, but it finds afterwards by manually running the above statement in the browser console. Seems like the `onchange` gets executed before PF modifies the markup. Or at least not all the markup...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am answering my own question. The working code look like the following:

```
<p:fileUpload disabled="#{userAccess.isDisabled()}"
    id="documentUpload"
    widgetVar="#{clientId}_documentUpload"
    label="#{msg['components.fileUpload.chooseDocument']}"
    uploadLabel="#{msg['components.fileUpload.uploadLabel']}"
    cancelLabel="#{msg['components.fileUpload.cancelLabel']}"
    invalidSizeMessage="#{nts['error.documentType.invalidFileSize']}"
    invalidFileMessage="#{cc.attrs.invalidFileTypeMessage}"
    fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.documentsHandler.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced"
    dragDropSupport="true"
    oncomplete="PF('#{clientId}_addPanel').collapse();"
    update="#{cc.clientId}:displayPanel"
    process="@this"
    allowTypes="#{cc.attrs.allowedTypes}"
    styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}"
    sizeLimit="1000000"
    pt:onchange="if(tagName == 'DIV' &amp;&amp; !!id &amp;&amp; #{!cc.attrs.isLogo}) { if(!!PF('#{clientId}_documentUpload').files.length) { PF('#{clientId}_addPanel').collapse(); PF('#{clientId}_editPanel').expand(); } }">
    <f:attribute name="document" value="#{cc.attrs.documentsHandler.document}" />
</p:fileUpload>
```

Basically what I change was the `passthrough` line which now looks like this:

```
pt:onchange="if(tagName == 'DIV' &amp;&amp; !!id &amp;&amp; #{!cc.attrs.isLogo}) { if(!!PF('#{clientId}_documentUpload').files.length) { PF('#{clientId}_addPanel').collapse(); PF('#{clientId}_editPanel').expand(); } }"
```

It basically filters out only the the `DIV` elements which have an id, because I saw that the file only gets attached to one element in the DOM and by making use of the widgetvar and the condition `if(!!PF('#{clientId}_documentUpload').files.length)` it basically works.

I don't know if it's the best or right way to do it, but as I said, it does the job.